# hook form submit, how to increase a database field?

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, drupal-6

im using hook form alter in drupal.

If the fields left empty I want it to get the last value submitted for the field and increase it by .01

Ive tried

```
function uc_pa_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  global $user;
$maxbid = db_result(db_query('SELECT MAX(amount) FROM {uc_auction_bids} WHERE nid = %d', $node->nid));
  $input01 = (($maxbid) ? $maxbid : 0) + .01;

drupal_write_record('table', $input01);
```

but it isnt updating with anything, I know $input01 works as I tried it in a different function.

if i change drupal_write_record('table', $input01); to the value submitted it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`drupal_write_record()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_write_record/6) expects the second argument to be an object, at the moment you're passing a number. Also, if you're trying to update a record you'll need to provide the table's primary keys as the third argument. Something like this:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM FROM {uc_auction_bids} WHERE nid = %d ORDER BY amount DESC LIMIT 1';
$obj = db_fetch_object(db_query($sql));
$obj->amount = (($obj->amount) ? $obj->amount: 0) + .01;

drupal_write_record('uc_auction_bids', $obj, array('bid'));
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the response. I couldnt relate most of it to what im doing though. Do I change mine to the above or do I add it on. If i use just the above im not declaring where im getting maxbid from

Comment: Ah, `$maxbid` has appeared! You can use `$obj->amount` in place of `$maxbid` (edited in the answer above). The above is loading a full row from `uc_auction_bid` into an object. It then changes the `amount` field for the object, and saves it back to the database. As `$obj` has all the details of the record (most importantly primary key), `drupal_write_record` will work. The above code could now be used in place of your original code (at least I'm pretty sure it could, try it :-))

Answer (score 0):

I'm new here and wish I could just comment rather than say I'm answering anything...

Anyway, what is $maxbid? It doesn't exist in the function before the comparison. Is it a global? Or should $input be $maxbid (or vice-versa) in your code sample?